# Return non-numeric characters

Tags: sql-server

I have 1 table.

[image]

Result
I want to show columns Names and Digits.

How do I return all rows that has a non-numeric characters in the Digits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNUMERIC` function

ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0.

```
SELECT names, digit 
FROM yourTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(digit) = 0
```

Comment: It should not return any records. Shoudln't it be SELECT names, digit
FROM table1 
WHERE digit LIKE '%[^0-9]%'. Just want to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PATINDEX`

```
Declare @SampleData as Table 
(
    Id int,
    Digit varchar(10)
)

insert into @SampleData
values 
( 1, '100'),(2,'2ab'),
(3,'200'), (4, ''), (5, 'a11')

select * from @SampleData
where PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Digit) > 0
```

Returns

```
Id  Digit
----------
2   2ab
5   a11
```